# Android14 cannot restrict camera usage

Tags: android, permissions

https://github.com/jfhr/disablecamera2

this source code is not working to me.

i have the device manager permission. but not work.

```
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, CameraPolicyReceiver.class);
    DevicePolicyManager policyManager = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    boolean isAdminActive = policyManager.isAdminActive(componentName);
```

isAdminActive is allways "ture".
but when i run

```
policyManager.setCameraDisabled(componentName, true);
```

this code send error code to me

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Caller does not have the required permissions for this user.
Permission required: android.permission.MANAGE_DEVICE_POLICY_CAMERA.
```

it is work under the android14, but now it is not.
i tried adding signature in my test apps. it also not work.

**UPDATE:**

ps. i added MANAGE_DEVICE_POLICY_CAMERA permission like below
[image]

it is not work...
And Same error

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Caller does not have the required permissions for this user.
Permission required: android.permission.MANAGE_DEVICE_POLICY_CAMERA.
```

**UPDATE2:**

[image]

With that so many permission, it is not work and same error.

**UPDATE3:**

finally, i found that url.
https://developers.google.com/android/work/device-admin-deprecation
device management is deprecated.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will be helpful, but maybe look into the ActivityCompat.requestPermissions() function, to be called in Activity class onCreate()

Comment: i add ```requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.MANAGE_DEVICE_POLICY_CAMERA}, DPM_ACTIVATION_REQUEST_CODE);``` in my Activity onCreate.() but nor works

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the given permission into your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DEVICE_POLICY_CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DEVICE_POLICY_ACROSS_USERS"/>
```

Given [the link](https://github.com/jfhr/disablecamera2/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) you provided, it doesn't seem like you're currently doing that.

This seems to be a new permission added for Android 14, so it makes sense that it works on lower version, but not on the version where this new permission was created.

**UPDATE:**

Reading further into [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#MANAGE_DEVICE_POLICY_CAMERA), it seems to suggest that you may also need to add this permission as well: `MANAGE_DEVICE_POLICY_ACROSS_USERS`.  I've updated the code accordingly.

Comment: Yes now i use Adnroid14 device. samsung Z fold4 for android 14

Comment: I've updated my answer with further information and instructions.  The docs seem to suggest you may need an extra permission in order for the first one to work.  Let me knowif that works for ya.

Comment: MANAGE_DEVICE_POLICY_ACROSS_USERS
I add that permission, and same.
now i am reading the docs, thanks